# SQL Server: automatically add a unique identifier to all rows inserted at one time

Tags: sql, sql-server, uniqueidentifier

The below SQL Server code successfully calculates and inserts the monthly pay for all employees along with their `staffID` number and inserts it into `Tablepayroll`.

```
INSERT INTO Tablepayroll (StaffID,Totalpaid)
(SELECT Tabletimelog.StaffID , Tabletimelog.hoursworked * Tablestaff.hourlypay
FROM Tabletimelog 
JOIN Tablestaff ON
Tabletimelog.StaffID = Tablestaff.StaffID)
```

However, I want to be able to also insert a `batchID`so that you can identify each time the above insert has been run and the records inserted by it at that time. Meaning that all staff payroll calculated  at the same time would have the same `batchID` number. Each subsequent `batchID` should just increase by 1.

Please see image below for visual explanation .

[image]

I think that `Select MAX(batch_id) + 1` would work , but I don't know how to include it in the insert statement.

Comment: Random thought: Create a trigger which inserts a single record into a second table with an auto increment column.  Use this to keep track of each batch.

Comment: I would not use MAX(BatchID) + 1 or the idea of inserting a record into a dummy table. You should look into sequences. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx What you describe is pretty much exactly what sequences are designed for.

Comment: Wouldn't storing the date of the insert be a lot more meaningful than a sequence? If you needed to generate an integer from this you could use  -  `Batch_id = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)`

Comment: I am also for @GarethD 's suggestion because it requires less logic to maintain.  But this will only work if datepaid is a DATETIME in case more than 1 batch happens per day as your example data suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use subquery to find latest `batch_id` from your current table using this query:

```
INSERT INTO TablePayroll (StaffID, TotalPaid, batch_id)
SELECT T1.StaffID
  , T1.HoursWorked * T2.HourlyPay
  , ISNULL((SELECT MAX(batch_id) FROM TablePayRoll), 0) + 1 AS batch_id
FROM TableTimeLog AS T1
INNER JOIN TableStaff AS T2
  ON T1.StaffID = T2.StaffID;
```

As you can see, I just add 1 to current `MAX(batch_id)` and that's it.
By the way, learn to use aliases. It will make your life easier

Yet another solution would be having your `batch_id` as a GUID, so you wouldn't have to create sequences or get `MAX(batch_id)` from current table.

```
DECLARE @batch_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NEWID();

INSERT INTO TablePayroll (StaffID, TotalPaid, batch_id)
SELECT T1.StaffID, T1.HoursWorked * T2.HourlyPay, @batch_id
FROM TableTimeLog AS T1
INNER JOIN TableStaff AS T2
  ON T1.StaffID = T2.StaffID;
```

Comment: For the first occurrence/batch need to test for the null and make it 0 otherwise everything is going to be NULL.  but other than that looks good

Comment: @Matt That's true. I'll make changes to query :) `COALESCE` should do just fine.

Comment: Even though it is not ANSI standard I might be inclined to use `ISNULL` instead of `COALESCE` here, `COALESCE` will cause the subquery to be execute twice because of the way it is expanded out to a case expression - `CASE WHEN (SELECT ...) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE (SELECT ...) END`. For further differences see [Deciding between COALESCE and ISNULL in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/)

Comment: @GarethD Fair enough. In this case it seems that `ISNULL` is better

Comment: Thankyou, I can confirm this works. As you can probably tell I'm a beginner and have been stumped on this for days!

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas Notice that your solution can provide a duplicate `batch_id` on the competitive insert

Comment: @AlexK I agree on that. But that would probably depend on Transaction Isolation Level in SQL Server. Unless you set that by yourself for this query. Correct me if I'm wrong.

And using Sequence would probably be a better idea in this case, I'd better go with way you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

First of all obtain the maximum value in a large table (based on the name of the table it must be big) can be very expensive. Especially if there is no index on the column `batch_id`

Secondly, pay attantion your solution `SELECT MAX(batch_id) + 1` may behave incorrectly when you will have competitive  inserts. Solution from @EvaldasBuinauskas without opening transaction and right isolation level can also lead to same `batch_id` if you run the two inserts at the same time in parallel.

If your SQL Server ver 2012 or higer you can try `SEQUENCE`. This at least ensures that no duplicates `batch_id`

Creating `SEQUENCE`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dbo.BatchID
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;  
-- DROP SEQUENCE dbo.BatchID
GO
```

And using it:

```
DECLARE @BatchID INT
SET @BatchID =  NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.BatchID;

INSERT INTO Tablepayroll (StaffID,Totalpaid, batch_id)
(SELECT Tabletimelog.StaffID , Tabletimelog.hoursworked * Tablestaff.hourlypay, @BatchID
    FROM Tabletimelog 
        JOIN Tablestaff ON  Tabletimelog.StaffID = Tablestaff.StaffID)
```

An alternative `SEQUENCE` may be additional table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Batch (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY 
        CONSTRAINT PK_Batch PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,DT DATETIME
        CONSTRAINT DF_Batch_DT DEFAULT GETDATE()
);
```

This solution works even on older version of the server.

```
DECLARE @BatchID INT

INSERT INTO dbo.Batch (DT)
    VALUES (GETDATE());

SET @BatchID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO Tablepayroll (StaffID,Totalpaid, batch_id)
(SELECT Tabletimelog.StaffID , Tabletimelog.hoursworked * Tablestaff.hourlypay, @BatchID
    FROM Tabletimelog ...
```

And yes,  all of these solutions do not guarantee the absence of holes in the numbering. This can happen during a transaction rollback (deadlock for ex.)

Comment: Thankyou Alex, I will try to understand sequences next.